# Tasa de variación

Tags: r

Parto de estos datos:

```
datos1 <- read.table(text = '
municipio   años    poblacion
Mun1    2000    50
Mun2    2000    300
Mun3    2000    1
Mun4    2000    100
Mun5    2000    5
Mun6    2000    20
Mun7    2000    20
Mun8    2000    3
Mun9    2000    20
Mun10   2000    20
Mun1    2001    100
Mun2    2001    50
Mun3    2001    10
Mun4    2001    30
Mun5    2001    20
Mun6    2001    60
Mun7    2001    40
Mun8    2001    20
Mun9    2001    20
Mun10   2001    3
Mun1    2002    20
Mun2    2002    5
Mun3    2002    20
Mun4    2002    5
Mun5    2002    20
Mun6    2002    10
Mun7    2002    20
Mun8    2002    20
Mun9    2002    5
Mun10   2002    0
Mun1    2003    20
Mun2    2003    25
Mun3    2003    20
Mun4    2003    10
Mun5    2003    20
Mun6    2003    10
Mun7    2003    30
Mun8    2003    20
Mun9    2003    60
Mun10   2003    20
Mun1    2004    20
Mun2    2004    10
Mun3    2004    20
Mun4    2004    10
Mun5    2004    20
Mun6    2004    34
Mun7    2004    20
Mun8    2004    20
Mun9    2004    34
Mun10   2004    21
', header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Quiero hacer la tasas de variación de la población año a año, es decir,

2001 con respecto al año 2000.

2002 con respecto al año 2001.

etc.

Para ello ordeno por año:

```
datos1[order(datos1$años),] -> datos1
```

Calculo la tasa:

```
library(TTR)

tasa <- datos1  %>%
  mutate(Tasa = ROC(poblacion, n = 10, type = "discrete"))
```

Quito la columna de población para poder cambiar a formato ancho:

```
tasa  <- tasa [,-c(3)]
```

Redondeo la tasa:

```
round(tasa$Tasa,2) -> tasa$Tasa
```

Lo paso a formato ancho:

```
tasa%>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = años, values_from = Tasa) -> tasa
```

Lo guardo:

```
write.csv(tasa ,'Tasa_Poblacion.csv', quote = F,row.names = FALSE)
```

Dudas:

1. ¿hay alguna otra forma más directa?
2. ¿cómo haría si tuviera más columnas y quisiera la tasa para cada una?, algo como esto:

   datos2 <- structure(list(municipio = c("Mun1", "Mun2", "Mun3", "Mun4",
   "Mun5", "Mun6", "Mun7", "Mun8", "Mun9", "Mun10", "Mun1", "Mun2",
   "Mun3", "Mun4", "Mun5", "Mun6", "Mun7", "Mun8", "Mun9", "Mun10",
   "Mun1", "Mun2", "Mun3", "Mun4", "Mun5", "Mun6", "Mun7", "Mun8",
   "Mun9", "Mun10", "Mun1", "Mun2", "Mun3", "Mun4", "Mun5", "Mun6",
   "Mun7", "Mun8", "Mun9", "Mun10", "Mun1", "Mun2", "Mun3", "Mun4",
   "Mun5", "Mun6", "Mun7", "Mun8", "Mun9", "Mun10"), años = c(2000,
   2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2001, 2001,
   2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2002, 2002, 2002,
   2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003,
   2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004,
   2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004), poblacion = c(50, 300, 1, 100,
   5, 20, 20, 3, 20, 20, 100, 50, 10, 30, 20, 60, 40, 20, 20, 3,
   20, 5, 20, 5, 20, 10, 20, 20, 5, 0, 20, 25, 20, 10, 20, 10, 30,
   20, 60, 20, 20, 10, 20, 10, 20, 34, 20, 20, 34, 21), nacimientos = c(4,
   0, 3, 0, 4, 3, 5, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 2, 0, 5, 0, 5, 4, 1,
   5, 3, 0, 5, 5, 1, 5, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 5, 0, 4, 2, 1, 5, 1, 2, 2,
   2, 3, 3, 0, 2, 4, 1), defunciones = c(2, 2, 1, 3, 1, 0, 0, 3,
   2, 4, 3, 4, 0, 3, 5, 1, 5, 4, 3, 0, 5, 1, 4, 2, 4, 2, 3, 2, 2,
   2, 1, 1, 0, 3, 2, 4, 3, 1, 4, 2, 0, 1, 1, 4, 5, 3, 3, 5, 3, 4
   )), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA,
   -50L))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes calcular la tasa directamente y de una manera más generalizable, agrupando por municipio y usando `lag(poblacion)` para obtener el valor anterior:

```
datos1 %>% 
  arrange(municipio, años) %>% 
  group_by(municipio) %>% 
  mutate(Tasa=(poblacion-lag(poblacion))/lag(poblacion)) %>% 
  select(municipio, años, Tasa) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = años, values_from = Tasa )
```

En caso de tener más variables, puedes usar `mutate_at` para aplicar el calculo de la tasa a varias:

```
datos2 %>% 
  arrange(municipio, años) %>% 
  group_by(municipio) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(poblacion, nacimientos, defunciones),
            list( ~ (. - lag(.)) / lag(.))
  ) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = años, 
              values_from = c(poblacion, nacimientos, defunciones) )
```

O incluso más genérico, si calculas sobre todas las variables menos municipio y años:

```
datos2 %>% 
  arrange(municipio, años) %>% 
  group_by(municipio) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(-años, -municipio),
            list( ~ (. - lag(.)) / lag(.))
  ) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = años, 
              values_from = c(-años, -municipio))
```

Comment: SI quisiera comparar 2002 vs 2000 en el primer ejemplo podria poner (poblacion-lag(poblacion,2))/lag(poblacion,2)). Pero para el segundo caso como tendría que podificar esta parte? list( ~ (. - lag(.)) / lag(.)). Probando con list( ~ (2 - lag(.)) / lag(.)) no sale lo que busco.

Comment: Debería funcionar así `list( ~ (. - lag(., 2)) / lag(., 2))`

Comment: Perfectísimo!!!